# How to get COUNT when using EXCEPT and UNION

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, union, except

Why can not I use the COUNT in a table?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM
(
(SELECT * FROM task.tableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM task.tableB)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM task.tableB EXCEPT SELECT * FROM task.tableA)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of query is called as inline view (Derived tables). An inline view is a SELECT statement in the FROM-clause of another SELECT statement.

Benefits:

1. We do not need to create the temporary table. This prevents the database from having too many objects, which is a good thing as each additional object in the database costs resources to manage.
2. We can use a single SQL query to accomplish what we want.

Execute your query with a table name "temp" as below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM task.tableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM task.tableB)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM task.tableB EXCEPT SELECT * FROM task.tableA)
) temp;
```

Comment: The proper term is `Derived Table` as you correctly mentioned. Inline view is not the proper term.

Comment: Nice use of "temp". Solved similar issue using except instead of union.